# Transposing In Particular Format

Tags: excel, vba

Today I finished the loops section of by VBA course and have been doing a few practices, but I've come across a problem I cannot seem to figure out.

I want to transpose data from sheet 1 to sheet to sheet 2.

Sheet 1

```
a   1   2   3
b   1   2   3   4   5   6
c   1   2   3   4
```

I am trying to write a macro which will transpose the data into Sheet 2 like this:

```
a   1
a   2
a   3
b   1
b   2
b   3
b   4
b   5
b   6
c   1
c   2
c   3
c   4
```

I tried to write some VBA code, but I have no idea how to approach this particular problem. I tried using Do Until Loops, but the issue I run into is how I get the the letters in sheet 1, column 1 to paste with their corresponding numbers in sheet 2.

A friend did some code for me to analyse, but it confused me even more. It works for this data set, but fails to do this with a larger data set (one where the letters go up to 'z').

Here is his code:

```
Sub transpose()
    Sheets(1).Select

    lrow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lrow1
        nums = 2

        Cells(i, nums).Select

        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
            nums = nums + 1
            Cells(i, nums).Select
        Loop

        Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, nums)).Copy
        Sheets(2).Select

        lrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        Cells(lrow2 + 1, 2).Select

        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, transpose:=True

        Sheets(1).Select

        Cells(i, 1).Copy

        Sheets(2).Select

        Cells(lrow2 + 1, 1).Select

        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, transpose:=False

        lrow3 = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        Cells(lrow2 + 1, 1).Select

        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(lrow2 + 1, 1), Cells(lrow3, 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault

        Sheets(1).Select
    Next i

    Sheets(2).Select

    Rows("1:1").Select

    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

https://pastebin.com/J45fmYKj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it for you ...

```
Public Sub TransformData()
    Dim lngRow As Long, lngEndRow As Long, objSrcSheet As Worksheet, objDestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim strLetter As String, strNumber As String, lngCol As Long, lngWriteRow As Long

    Set objSrcSheet = Sheet1
    Set objDestSheet = Sheet2

    lngEndRow = objSrcSheet.Range("A" & objSrcSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With objSrcSheet
        For lngRow = 1 To lngEndRow
            strLetter = .Cells(lngRow, 1)

            If strLetter <> "" Then
                For lngCol = 2 To .Columns.Count
                    strNumber = .Cells(lngRow, lngCol)

                    If strNumber = "" Then Exit For

                    lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1

                    objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 1) = strLetter
                    objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 2) = strNumber
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

... I decided to give you an entire solution.  Right or wrong, best or worst, that's how I would do it and given you're learning, I hope it helps you.  It also takes an approach where SELECT is not being used, that will do nothing more than slow you down and is considered to be extremely bad practice.

It assumes my source worksheet looks like the below image.  I hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. It is helping with the learning, in that I'm trying to understand the code. What I didn't seem to think of was a loop within a loop.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A simple Excel related method is to use `Power Query` aka `Get&Transform`. Select the first column and then `unpivot` the `Other` columns.  All that can be done from the User Interface.

If you want to have a macro that uses loops to accomplish the same end result, I would do as below.  Note that I do the looping in VBA arrays rather than using repeated calls to/from the worksheet.  This is a much faster method.

```
Option Explicit
Sub due()
    'Declare the variables
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim lRC() As Long
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long

'Set Worksheet and Range variables
'Determine Last Row and Column of the range, assuming starts in A1
Set WS1 = Sheet1
Set WS2 = Sheet2
    Set rRes = WS2.Cells(1, 1)
lRC = LastRowCol(WS1.Name)

'Read the source data into a VBA array
'much faster than operating on the worksheet
With WS1
    Set rSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRC(0), lRC(1)))
    vSrc = rSrc
End With

'size the results array
'note that `Count` will only count the numeric entries, which is what we want
'might have to use a different computation if there is not a nice text/number
'differentiation between column 1 and the rest of the data
ReDim vRes(1 To WorksheetFunction.Count(rSrc), 1 To 2)

'Here is the loop
'we go through the source data one row at a time
'writing to the results array as you can see
'Need to check for blank entries since not all rows are the
' same length.
K = 0
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    For J = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
        If vSrc(I, J) <> "" Then
            K = K + 1
            vRes(K, 1) = vSrc(I, 1)
            vRes(K, 2) = vSrc(I, J)
        End If
    Next J
Next I

'write the results to the destination worksheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
End With

End Sub

Function LastRowCol(Worksht As String) As Long()
Application.Volatile
    Dim WS As Worksheet, R As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim L(1) As Long
Set WS = Worksheets(Worksht)
With WS
    Set R = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                    searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

    If Not R Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = R.Row
        LastCol = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
                    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Else
        LastRow = 1
        LastCol = 1
    End If
End With

L(0) = LastRow
L(1) = LastCol
LastRowCol = L
End Function
```

**Source Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to navigate (and certainly faster) to work within arrays.

```
Option Explicit

Sub stackTranspose()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, vals As Variant, arr As Variant

    'collect original values into source array
    With Worksheets(1)
        vals = .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion.Value2
    End With

    'redimension target array and set k for first 'row'
    ReDim arr(1 To Application.Count(vals), 1 To 2)
    k = 1

    'loop through source and transfer transposed values
    For i = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
        For j = LBound(vals, 2) + 1 To UBound(vals, 2)
            'is there a value to transfer?
            If vals(i, j) <> vbNullString Then
                arr(k, 1) = vals(i, LBound(vals, 2))
                arr(k, 2) = vals(i, j)
                'increment target 'row'
                k = k + 1
            Else
                'blank value; move to next source 'row'
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    'put target values into Sheeet2
    With Worksheets(2)
        .Cells(1, "A").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With

End Sub
```